# Aptana Studio 3.0.6 block mode select broken

Tags: selection, aptana, block, mode, aptana3

I am no longer able to toggle block mode selection in Studio 3.0.6. It was working in 3.0.5. Has anyone been able to turn off and on block mode selection?

Comment: How do you engage in block select mode?

Answer (score 1):

Check your word wrap settings (Preferences > Aptana Studio > Editors). Block select doesn't work with word wrap enabled.